# If the life in the Akirah becomes eternal then, does it mean, that life is equal to Allah's life as Allah is eternal?

Tags: allah, shirk, doubts, contradiction

I am having a doubt :
The doubt is,
1. If Life after death is eternal,
2. We know, Allah is eternal.
3. And in the (sura Ikhlas: 4) Allah said,
"None is comparable to him."

So, is the concept of 1 and 2, contradicted to 3 ?

May Allah give us refuge in Him from all doubts and thoughts put into heart by devil and from the whisper of the devil.
May Allah help us to get solution of doubts.

Comment: Life in the Hereafter will be forever. But we all had a beginning unlike God. He always existed and will always exist.  So we are not comparable to Him. Also if He so wishes He can easily turn us to dust just like God has said on Judgement Day after all have been taken account of, God will turn the animals to dust and those destined for Hell will wish if they too could have been turned to dust instead of being given an eternal life.

Comment: We can only fit the description of Allah if we are like one of those 4 verses of surah 112. verse 112:2, is eternal and absolute. Absolute in the sense that he is not deficent in any way he needs no-one and everyone is in need of Him. Even if we are eternal we are in complete need of Allah whereas Allah does not need us at all. in fact some translation don't say eternal and absolute but say Allah besought of All,  needing none.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same. Allah is eternal meaning that He has no beginning and no end. Life after death has a beginning and no end. Also Allah's existence is inherent to His person, whereas the existence after death of a people is granted and sustained by Allah, not due to themselves.